# Excel VBA Active Chart Data - Copy excel data to powerpoint excel chart data

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range, powerpoint

I have a problem while using ChartData in Excel VBA.

```
With PP_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("Chart 3").Chart.ChartData
        .ActivateChartDataWindow
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        .Workbook.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(34, 34)).Value2 = worksheet_name.Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(36, 35)).Value2
        .Workbook.Sheets(1).Calculate
        .Workbook.Close savechanges:=False
    End With
```

But the vba got error of "Run time error '438' : Object doesn't support this property or method" in this line

```
.Workbook.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(34, 34)).Value2 = worksheet_name.Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(36, 35)).Value2
```

The thing is, while I tried it using RowColumn mode (ex. A1, B2) it works. But I need using number so i can do loop easily.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You need to fully qualify your range objects. Something like this `.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range(.Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1), .Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(34, 34)).Value2 = worksheet_name.Range(.Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(4, 2), .Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(36, 35)).Value2`

Comment: I used `.Workbook.Sheets(1).` as an example. Replace with the relevant sheet

Comment: Edited: works well !! thanks siddharth

Comment: 2 things... `1` your cells object is still not fully qualified. `2` what is `workbook/worksheet_name`?